# Failure to build wheel / "Error: INCLUDE Environment Variable is empty"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, environment-variables

I am using Python 2.7.11 and am trying to pip install modules however a few of them are failing. The message I get is "Failure to build wheel for 'X'" and "Error: INCLUDE Environment Variable is empty".

I tried to install Scrapy, LXML and Twisted and those failed. Some other random modules I tried installed fine.

I have installed pyOpenSSL, added python27 and python27/scripts to environment.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you installed python-dev?

Answer (score 2):

I tried both the solutions offered, none worked.

I installed Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7, download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266). Then run:

```
pip install scrapy
```

That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to install the pre-compiled version of lxml. You can find it [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.6.0). If you use the .exe you can point it directly to your python root folder.

After that:

1. close and re-open cmd
2. `pip install your_package` (make sure cmd is in the correct directory)
3. enjoy having no frustrating lxml errors!

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pre built library from this link if you are on windows:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Choose the relevant library given python version and desktop config. For example
I want to install apell in python 3.6 and winamd64 then download this:

aspell_python-1.15-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Now go to your console and type

`pip install path-to-.whl`

and that's it.