# mysql workbench can't import pyodbc

Tags: python, mysql

I have installed mysql workbench v. 8.0.13, and am trying to run the migration tool, but I get an error:

```
Could not import the pyodbc python module. You need pyodbc 2.1.8 or newer for migrations from RDBMSes other than MySQL.
```

I have installed pyodbc:

```
Python 3.7.0 (default, Sep 28 2018, 16:44:32) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20180831] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
>>> pyodbc.version
'4.0.24'
```

How can I fix this problem?

```
OS: Linux my-pc 4.19.0-3-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Oct 27 22:40:22 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was necessary to install python version 2.7 and pyodbc for it

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem on Windows and replacing python 3.8 install with a 2.7 one wasn't enough.

That was very weird because when I launched a python console, I was able to import pyodbc module. But when I launched the python.exe that is included in Mysql Workbench installation directory, the module couldn't be loaded (an error was telling that a dll couldn't be find, without telling which one).

I first thought this was related to a sys.path difference between these two contexts, but the loading error persisted after having make the paths identical.

Finally I found a python27.dll file in the Mysql Workbench directory, and renaming this file to python27.notdll (to prevent if from being loaded) solved the pyodbc loading problem.

I don't know what could be the side effects of this dll disabling, but as far as python 2.7 is already installed and works, I don't think this should be a problem.

Anyway, the migration wizard is now working.

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me - I think if someone were to go to the mysql workbench and specifically install pyodbc there using pip, it might work.  For me it was too much trouble to try it out since I had already installed python separately and placed it on my path.

Answer (score 2):

In my situation I was trying to use SQL WorkBench's database migration wizard to [migrate SQL Server tables to MySQL](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/how-migrate-mssql-mysql) and ran into this pyodbc error.

Building onto [@Flo answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64502240/194872) for Windows 10:

1. Uninstall all python installations (this step may be optional but I had many installs and wanted to work from a clean slate)
2. install [python 2.7.x 64-bit](https://www.python.org/downloads/). During the installation, register the python.exe to the $Path/command line (this was un-checked by default so I had to enable it).
3. Install [MySQL WorkBench 64-bit](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) (see under the "Other Downloads" section, v8.0.22 in my case)
4. Install MS [VC++ Compiler for Python](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266) (as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50294736/194872) to solve the "Error: INCLUDE Environment Variable is empty" error)
5. Open cmd.exe (command line) and type: cd C:\Python27\Scripts
6. run pip command: pip install -Iv pyodbc==2.1.8
7. Rename the Sql WorkBench's copy of python27.dll to python27.**nodll** under "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\
8. Start SQL WorkBench > Database menu > Migration Wizard > click "Start Migration" button and the pyodbc error should no longer show.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Windows 10, same MySQLWorkbench version. As soon as I rename python27.dll workbench just refuses to open. The python command is correctly mapped to my fresh python 2.7 install as well so no clues as to why it hasn't worked.

Comment: @Sk446 try checking the startup log? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html. You could also try right clicking sql workbench icon > run as administrator to make sure its not a UAC or permissions thing.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with MySQL Workbench v. 8.0.22. Resolved it by installing Python2.7 and renaming the python27.ddl to force the MySQL Workbench to use it from python installation

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and came across this question first in my searching. However, the following question and answer is what finally solved my problem: [Issue while starting migration wizard in mysql workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679366/issue-while-starting-migration-wizard-in-mysql-workbench)

I downgraded MySQL Workbench to 8.0.20 and pyodbc error was gone!

There are additional steps (as per above link) you can take to copy off the necessary files and upgrade again:

1. Try to install MySQL Workbench with lower version, e.g. 8.0.20. (It's easy with MySql Installer)
2. Find file "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\python\site-packages\pyodbc.pyd" and save it.
3. Then upgrade MySQL Workbench to the latest (in my case 8.0.22)
4. Copy previously saved file pyodbc.pyd back to the "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\python\site-packages"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34898718)

Comment: The essential part was downgrading MySQL Workbench, but I've added the additional instructions for how to re-upgrade as well for those interested.