# Issue while starting migration wizard in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, mysql-workbench, database-migration

I am trying to migrate from postgres to mysql database using mysql workbench. I have installed postgres into my system and its working fine.

When i start migration wizard and dependency error shows as,

```
Could not import the pyodbc python module. You need pyodbc 2.1.8 or newer or migrations from RDBMSes other than MYSQL.
```

then after ignoring this error when i actually start the migration process it shows me another error in log,

```
SystemError: ImportError("No module named pyodbc"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.connect
ERROR: Error during Connect to source DBMS: ImportError("No module named pyodbc"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.connect
ERROR: Exception in task 'Connect to source DBMS': SystemError('ImportError("No module named pyodbc"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.connect',)
```

After googling a bit I reinstalled or newly installed few things, but it did not work as the same error popups every time.
I tried renaming the python file , dll file , manually copied installed pyodbc.py, installed different versions of python but still the same.

how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue

1. Try to install MySQL Workbench with lower version, e.g. 8.0.20. (It's easy with MySql Installer)
2. Find file **"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\python\site-packages\pyodbc.pyd"** and save it.
3. Then upgrade MySQL Workbench to the latest (in my case 8.0.22)
4. Copy previously saved file **pyodbc.pyd** back to the **"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\python\site-packages"**

*Please leave a comment if it works for you*

Comment: Yes!  I downgraded to 8.0.18.  Copied the pyodbc.pyd file, installed 8.0.20 and replaced the file and it worked!  Thanks

Comment: it would have been better if someone would directly share that file with the community, that would be a better help

Comment: Can you elaborate on the MySql Installer?  When i run the msi I don't get an option to downgrade.  How are you getting the mysql installer (windows 10)?

Comment: @PaulGibson Yes, there is no direct option to downgrade. You have to remove and install with lower version (MySQL Installer allows you select any version to install).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the answers I found worked for me (as of Workbench version 8.0.34).  Installing Python native and renaming DLLs caused it not to launch (and no logging as to why, either).  Installing the older version (8.0.18), copying pyodbc.pyd to a safe place, installing the latest, then putting pyodbc.py in its proper home also didn't work (it launched, but same error message).

The only thing that worked for me was uninstalling Workbench completely and installing the older (.18 from 4 years ago!) version, and then it worked like a champ.  Clearly, this is some bug that they have not addressed.